# Can Graphaware community edition be used on Neo4j enterprise edition?

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

I'm curious if the Graphaware framework edition (community vs enterprise) must match the Neo4j edition?

Comment: What you mean by Graphaware community?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to clarify I meant Graphaware framework. Will edit question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to what MicTech said: there are two aspects, licensing and technical compatibility. Licensing is explained here: http://graphaware.com/licences/

Technically, the framework edition on the [downloads](http://products.graphaware.com) page has to match your Neo4j edition. Then you can use any module.

The confusing bit can be the word "enterprise". You can use the GraphAware Framework for Neo4j Enterprise free of charge, provided you don't violate the GPL v3 licence. That's the .jar called graphaware-server-enterprise-all-x.x.x.x.jar.

You can also choose to join the paid GraphAware Enterprise program, which gives you:

- all GraphAware software licensed under a commercial licence (GACL)
- modules that aren't freely available (security, audit, schema enforcement)
- enterprise support for all GraphAware software

Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

[GraphAware Enterprise](http://graphaware.com/enterprise/) is only for the enterprise version of Neo4j.

Other GraphAware tools and libraries which are publicly available should work with both Neo4j editions.

[Here](http://graphaware.com/products/) you can find more information.